# Entity framework : Manually set an "Identity" value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I am currently using the entity-framework with SQLite. I am currently inserting entity with an ID (that is autogenerated by SQLite but it is *not* autoincrement'ed.  See [this](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)). This field is marked as `StoreGeneratedPattern = "Identity"` in the .edmx.

I would like to insert entity in the table and be able to specify an ID (so the database won't have to generate one).

Comment: Suppose a migration from a XML format with ID to this database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the field is configured with `StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity` you cannot modify it in the application. That is how it works. If you try to do it EF will either skip your modification or throws exception. If you need to define key on the client you don't have to generate key in the database and you must set `StoreGeneratedPattern.None`.

Comment: This was helpful for me. Just want to add that for code-first EF you can enable this behavior by adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute to your _ID_ property.